# How to convert one pixel format to another? (420f to n12)

Tags: ios, objective-c, video-processing, core-video, pixelformat

So I'm getting frames in CV420YpCbCr8BiPlanarFullRange pixel format. That is a bi-planar 4:2:0 thingy.

I need to convert it to some of the formats consumed by a third party library, for example this one.
[image]

At first sight it seems that it's the same format, but unfortunately the picture is mangled. Any ideas where is the problem? And what are some libraries that allow for conversion between the formats?

```
video_frame.p_data = (uint8_t *)CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddressOfPlane(pixelBuffer, 1);
```

doesn't work. Neither does getting the base address of the structure.

Comment: Can you provide a link to a testable: `CV420YpCbCr8BiPlanarFullRange pixel format`

Comment: Hey. There are two ways to do this: either try my example (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ceSBizSm9WIYwKyQfDn1oiVvLq8UBCvc/view?usp=sharing) - for that you'll need to download the NDI Sdk and drop it to the folder. Or you simply comment out the lines dependent on the sdk (it's like 5 lines in SampleHandler.mm) and you're off to the races.

Comment: @Novellizator Have you found a solution?

Comment: @Vika yes long long time ago and I barely remember it. i did extract the planes, memset them together and voila. i no longer have access to the sources, so I cannot help ;(